# Gmail authenticate password of php website project

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I have problem about the coding for php. I'm still new in php/html webpage. I get revision and tips from Sir Derrick Abucheri in youtube:

The link is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-_bAZdYEy4

My question is how to get authenticate for gmail. I try to change but I still now get the answer, here is the code :

Thank you

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'shirokamikaze111@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `@` like this, it suppresses errors and makes things extremely difficult to troubleshoot. If you removed those from your code, you'll probably get an error which will explain to you what is wrong.

Comment: Get rid of the YOLO operator (`@`) that suppresses errors, and *don't* use `stripslashes` arbitrarily like this. Email is not subject to SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should also never spoof the From: address of an email. These have a high likelihood of being rejected because they're not legitimate emails from that user. Instead use a From: address that you control.